# Why do I have no resource groups in Azure when trying to install Windows VM?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-group

I am absolutely new to the cloud thing. I need to setup a Windows VM in the cloud along with a Tesla GPU to run a 3D application. 
Now, with the help of this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCRwqoVpsLA), I almost created a Windows VM except for the fact that I have 0 resource groups.

[image: *No available items* screenshot]

I need a bit of guidance in here. Can someone please help me out?

Also, does it have anything to do with the subscription I chose?

Comment: Have you created any resource group?

Comment: Have you tried googling "azure resource group"? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/manage-resource-groups-portal

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't have any resource group created yet. Select create a new resource group instead.

Or you can type resource group on the search bar at the top to create one, then you come back to create your VM and you should see the resource group you created

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/manage-resource-groups-portal

I hope this helped.